# Is Google using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I've been curious about this for a while now, hopefully this isn't to secretive and some Googlers could give some information about this?

Comment: use for what? it's pretty large corporation - there surely is someone using python3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Googler, but I'd say the answer is most likely: yes.

After all, [Guido van Rossum](http://www.python.org/~guido/), creator of Python, has been working for Google since 2005. And it's not really like using Python 3 is such a secretive thing. A language upgrade isn't such a "killer feature" that will sweep all competition off their feet.

Do know that using Python 3 in house is one thing, and providing Python 3 APIs is another.

Case in point: Google has been using [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) since 2006 in its mission critical applications. This means Guice has probably been under development earlier than 2006. Yet, the first public release of Guice has been in March 2007.

There is no reason to believe they aren't doing the same with Python.

As you can see, my answer is highly speculative, but it does use some common sense based on facts and previous Google's moves.

Answer (score 3):

No, see e.g. https://code.google.com/p/or-tools/ which is Python 2 only.

Python is far from the main language at Google anyway, see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/unladen-swallow/TtvEBvVEZD4

Also, " Today dozens of Google engineers use Python,"  http://www.python.org/about/quotes/, which is a small fraction of all engineers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Google employee, on Google App Engine they still provide Python 2.5